# Switch User in RedHat like XP

Tags: linux, switch, user

In our cluster, RedHat4 & 5 machines, if someone locks the computer and walks away no body can use it.  Is there a feature in RedHat5, Gnome, KDE etc that would allow for the option of switching users at the lock screen, so more than one person can be logged in?

Thanks,
rd42

Comment: IIRC, you can start another xserver.  Hit ctrl+alt+f8 (f7 is default). Login at prompt and type `startx`

Comment: I think it's important to mention you're talking about [RHEL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux) and not [Red Hat Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux), which was discontinued in 2004.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Gnome version in EL5 is from before they had user-switch functionality from the screensaver dialog. They'll need to switch to another VT and log in there, or wait for EL6.

Comment: RHEL 6 has now been [released](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Release_Notes/).

Comment: As listed by Stephen in the comments, you can do this with ctrl+alt+fX (where X is a number from 1-9 not including 7)

Comment: Once they have a command prompt, create a new graphical session with `gdmflexiserver`. The Switch User button in EL6 runs `gdmflexiserver --startnew Standard`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always ask them to use "Switch User" instead

Application->System Tools->Switch User